# I need to convert from Class component to functional this code

Tags: reactjs

I need to convert from Class component to functional components this code.

This is a problem for me because I'm looking for this but I didn't find solutions

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: '',
    rememberMe: false
  };
 
  handleChange = (event) => {
    const input = event.target;
    const value = input.type === 'checkbox' ? input.checked : input.value;
 
    this.setState({ [input.name]: value });
  };
 
  handleFormSubmit = () => {};

  handleFormSubmit = () => {
    const { user, rememberMe } = this.state;
    localStorage.setItem('rememberMe', rememberMe);
    localStorage.setItem('user', rememberMe ? user : '');
  };
  
  componentDidMount() {
    const rememberMe = localStorage.getItem('rememberMe') === 'true';
    const user = rememberMe ? localStorage.getItem('user') : '';
    this.setState({ user, rememberMe });
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
        <label>
          User: <input name="user" value={this.state.user} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input name="rememberMe" checked={this.state.rememberMe} onChange={this.handleChange} type="checkbox"/> Remember me
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
      </form>
    );
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow. With questions like this it is preferable for you to try first and *then* post an issue with your [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code attempt, with included details about any error messages and what is or isn't working as expected. SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: What is specific problem you are facing here?

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is a place where you should go as **the last resort** after you've **exhausted all other options**. Everyone helping here is doing so for free, and asking someone to rewrite entire code for you is not the use of StackOverflow, but since I want you a warm welcome as a new contributor, It would look something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const FunctionalApp = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [rememberMe, setRememberMe] = useState(false);

  const handleChangeUser = (event) => {
    const input = event.target;
    const value = input.value;
 
    setUser(value);
  };

  const handleChangeRememberMe = (event) => {
    const input = event.target;
    const value = input.checked;
 
    setRememberMe(value);
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('rememberMe', rememberMe);
    localStorage.setItem('user', rememberMe ? user : '');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const rememberMe = localStorage.getItem('rememberMe') === 'true';
    const user = rememberMe ? localStorage.getItem('user') : '';

    setUser(user);
    setRememberMe(rememberMe);
  }, [])

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
      <label>
        User: <input name="user" value={user} onChange={handleChangeUser}/>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input name="rememberMe" checked={rememberMe} onChange={handleChangeRememberMe} type="checkbox"/> Remember me
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
    </form>
  );

}
```

Check out [the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6ryf7y) on StackBlitz, where you can compare with your original component.